# Quais as diferenças entre ViewBag, ViewData e TempData?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Estava pesquisando a respeito da forma de passar dados para uma *view*, ou melhor, persistir os dados de uma *controller* para a *view*.

Gostaria de saber dentre as 3 formas citadas no título:

- Quais as diferenças entre elas?
- Em que casos a utilização de uma é mais recomendada que outra?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## ViewBag

É um objeto dinâmico com propriedades criadas no controlador e que é acessível na visão, depois disto ela desaparece. Ela mantém o tipo de cada membro, ainda que o compilador não possa fazer verificações. Em geral é o mais adequado.

```
ViewBag.Mensagem = "O que deseja passar aqui";
ViewBag.Valor = 1;
```

Consumo:

```
@ViewBag.Mensagem
@ViewBag.Valor
```

Na verdade em boa parte dos casos uma tupla ou um tipo criado para o fim específico (*viewmodel*) costuma ser mais adequado em C#. Seria o caso para passar alguma informação isolada bem simples e que não pertence aos dados que devem constar no modelo desta visão. É só minha opinião, mas eu acho gambiarra para a filosofia do C#. Quando se deseja este tipo de flexibilidade deveria usar outra linguagem. Eu acho que a maneira como se constroem essas aplicações web leva a muito *biolerplate*  como este. Mas objetivamente é usado para passar dados de "configuração" da página.

## ViewData

É um dicionário de objetos, e só deveria ser usado quando não se sabe a composição do que será o objeto, já que os elementos não possuem tipos e sintaxe de acesso a eles um pouco desconfortável. Acho que em C# não faz muito sentido usar, considero um recurso obsoleto, ainda que possa ter utilidade em algum tipo de arquitetura.

```
ViewData["mensagem"] = "O que deseja passar aqui";
ViewData["valor"] = 1;
```

Consumo:

```
@(string)ViewData["mensagem"] //tecnicamente esta conversão pode ser feita automaticamente
@(int)ViewData["valor"] //a conversão não é necessária se apenas deseja imprimir
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/ViewBag.cs).

## TempData

Aqui o objetivo é bem diferente. É um dicionário também, mas seu tempo de vida é a sessão daquele usuário. É usado apenas para manter valor entre as chamadas no controlador e não para passar dados para a visão.

Lembre que a visão está muito ligada ao controlador, esses objetos acima só servem para facilitar a comunicação entre elas, são totalmente dispensáveis. Já o `TempData` é mais necessário, ainda que existam outros mecanismos similares. Sem este mecanismo ou algo parecido teria que ficar mantendo estado no cliente e ficar transmitindo todas as vezes, correndo riscos de segurança e confiabilidade. Ele é muito mais que um facilitador para mandar dados, tem toda uma infraestrutura por trás dele que permite a "persistência" dos dados relevantes para a sessão.

Answer (score 0):

A ViewData e ViewBag servem para transportar pequenas quantidades de dados entre views ou de controllers para views.

Na ViewData os dados viajam do controlador para a view através de um dicionário "ViewDataDictionary".

Este "ViewDataDictionary" é uma classe dicionário que é chamada "ViewData" e ate essa propriedade dictionary ViewData pode ser usada para preencher os dados pra você passar para uma view.

ViewBag é apenas um invólucro dinâmico em torno de ViewData.
Com a ViewBag você não precisa escrever 'dynamic', ele usa a palavra-chave dynamic internamente.

Dessa forma, ViewBag  pode ser vista como a biblioteca de dados dinâmico.

E a TempData e como uma sessão de servidor mais de curta duração que tem um tempo de vida maior que a ViewBag e ViewData porque ela dura desde sua criação até ser chamado, so quando houver um request da informação do TempData, que o TempData vai se tornará nulo novamente.